# how to change background color of view of RecyclerView at specific position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have an activity and it contain one recyclerview and below it viewPager.
when i swipe the page of view pager then i set the background color of recycleview item at the position respective to the **position** of viewPager item.
it is working fine, when the recyclerView item is visible to the screen.

**But my Problem is here**

when i scrolled the recyclerview item and then scrolling my viewPager item.then it giving me a **null pointer exception** .

to solve this problem, i programmatically scroll the recyclerView item to current viewPager item **position**,and then tring to set the backgroung color but still i got **nullPointerException**

```
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            if (position >=previousPosition) {


                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position+1);
            } else {


                if(position>0)
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position-1);
            }
            previousPosition = position;

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder 

       viewHolder=recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

            if(viewHolder!=null)
                  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lightGrey);
            else
            {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

             recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lightGrey);    //  **this line giving me nullPointerException**

            }






        }
```

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: in your `onBindViewHolder` put this `if (position%2==0){  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lightGrey);}else{  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yello);}` 
it changes the `carview color like even odd`

Comment: But I want to change, background colour when i change, the page of viewpager,